# Manhwa/webtoon about a knight saving a kidnapped princess; the knight later becomes the villain he himself defeated

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

The manhwa was very loosely based on Norse mythology and was fully colored.

In it, we could witness the story of a knight, first saving a kidnapped princess, and then, while trying to protect her so she doesn't get kidnapped again, he slowly starts getting darker, until he becomes the villain (demon king?) who originally kidnapped her and was defeated by the knight (himself), getting trapped on a circular, self-fulfilling destiny.

I kind of remember that the implication of the story was that the knight/villain was the real victim of the story, and he was trapped by the princess on his protector/savior role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. The name is [A Fairytale for the Demon lord](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/AFairytaleForTheDemonLord)